# How do I use HttpBuilder with a partial path in the URL?

Tags: spock, grails-3.3, httpbuilder-ng

In my Grails app, I have a config property which includes a partial URL path, like this:
`http://apis.mycompany.com/my-api/v1/`

I want to invoke endpoints using this URL with `HttpBuilder`:

```groovy
class MyApiService {
    @Value('${myApiUrl}')
    String myApiUrl

    def http

    @PostConstruct()
    init() {
        http = HttpBuilder.configure {
            request.uri = myApiUrl
        }
    }

    def getData() {
        http.get() {
            // This doesn't work!!
            request.uri.path = 'resource/data'
        }
    }
}
```

The `request.uri.path` erases the existing path segment:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: http://apis.mycompany.comresource/data
```

I was able to work around this:

```groovy
request.raw = "${myApiUrl}resource/data"
```

...but I can't get Ersatz to work with `raw` in my Spock test:

```groovy
def setup() {
    ersatz = new ErsatzServer()
    service.myApiUrl = ersatz.httpUrl + '/'
}

void "getData() - should call the endpoint"() {
    given:
    def jsonData = '[{"person": "Someone"}]'

    ersatz.expectations {
        get("/resource/data") {
            called 1
            responder {
                content jsonData, 'application/json;chartset=UTF-8'
            }
        }
    }

    when:
    def result = service.getData()

    then:
    result == jsonData
}
```

The URL being assigned to `raw` is: `http://localhost:-1/resources/data`

This results in an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null

    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:176)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1132)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at groovyx.net.http.JavaHttpBuilder$Action.lambda$execute$2(JavaHttpBuilder.java:147)
    at groovyx.net.http.JavaHttpBuilder$ThreadLocalAuth.with(JavaHttpBuilder.java:331)
    at groovyx.net.http.JavaHttpBuilder$Action.execute(JavaHttpBuilder.java:122)
    at groovyx.net.http.JavaHttpBuilder.createAndExecute(JavaHttpBuilder.java:374)
    at groovyx.net.http.JavaHttpBuilder.doGet(JavaHttpBuilder.java:381)
    at groovyx.net.http.HttpObjectConfigImpl.nullInterceptor(HttpObjectConfigImpl.java:47)
    at groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.get(HttpBuilder.java:346)
    at groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.get(HttpBuilder.java:1297)
    at com.mycompany.MyApiService.getData(...)
    at com.mycompany.MyApiServiceSpec.getData(...)
```

Is this a bug in HttpBuilder, or am I doing it wrong? Help appreciated!

**Update:**

I thought Ersatz would start when constructed, but it turns out I was wrong. Calling `start()` before using the URL fixed the -1 port number:

```groovy
def setup() {
    ersatz = new ErsatzServer()
    ersatz.start()
    service.myApiUrl = ersatz.httpUrl + '/'
}
```

Now, the builder is getting a seemingly valid URL:
`http://localhost:52180/resources/data`

...but the Ersatz server gives a message that the expectation is not matched.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expectations for Expectations (ErsatzRequest): <GET>, "/resources/data" were not met.. Expression: (com.stehno.ersatz.impl.ErsatzRequest -> com.stehno.ersatz.impl.ErsatzRequest) r.verify()

    at com.stehno.ersatz.impl.ExpectationsImpl.verify_closure2(ExpectationsImpl.groovy:365)
    at com.stehno.ersatz.impl.ExpectationsImpl.verify(ExpectationsImpl.groovy:364)
    at com.stehno.ersatz.ErsatzServer.verify(ErsatzServer.groovy:522)
    at com.mycompany.MyApiServiceSpec.cleanup(...)
```

The Ersatz docs indicate that the unmatched request should be printed out, but it only prints the above stack trace (and an HttpNotFoundException).

Comment: You need to add `reportToConsole true` to the Ersatz constructor config to get the report written to the console, otherwise its just written to the logs.

Comment: I would suggest turning on some logging - DEBUG level should give you a lot more information from both HttpBuilder-NG and Ersatz so you can see what both are doing. My thought would be that the problem is with the HttpBuilder-NG config. The `raw` method is really meant to solve url-encoding issues.

Comment: Lastly, if I remember right, HB-NG does not properly append to a path when the host and partial path are specified in the configuration block. Generally you want to have the host configured there and then the path configured per request. I could be wrong, its been a while.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works to just append the path instead of assigning it:

```
request.uri.path += 'resource/data'
```